# AngularJS 2.0 on IE Edge browser gets infinite loop / SCRIPT28 "out of stack space"

Tags: angular, stack-overflow, infinite-loop, microsoft-edge

I built a simple AngularJS 2.0 app that runs well in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE or Edge. I've boiled down a very simple file that will fail:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Gets out of stack space error in IE Edge Browser</title>
  <!--script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script-->
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/Rx.umd.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
  <script>
(function(app) {

 app.SetupComponent = ng.core.Component({
  selector: 'setup',
  directives: [],
  template: '<h3>Hey</h3>'
 }).Class({
  constructor: function() {}
 });

 app.AppComponent = ng.core.Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [app.SetupComponent],
  template: '<setup></setup>'
 }).Class({
  constructor: function() {}
 });

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
 });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <app>Loading...</app>
 </body>
</html>
```

Specifically, on Chrome or Firefox, it properly outputs "Hey", but on IE Edge on Windows 10, it gets console output like:

SCRIPT28: Out of stack space

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a plnkr? I just copied & pasted that snippet and it works fine on IE Edge

Comment: I added this to https://plnkr.co/edit/OkT1nSxwb1oriXuMAOMI, where it fails for me on Microsoft Edge for Windows 10, although it works in Internet Explorer. A colleague of mine says it fails in his IE. Here's how it fails in Edge:
EXCEPTION: Error: Out of stack space
   EXCEPTION: Error: Out of stack space
   browser_adapter.ts (73,7)
   STACKTRACE:
   browser_adapter.ts (73,7)
   Error: Out of stack space
   at BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.createElement (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-all.umd.dev.js:29705:10)
   at DomRenderer.prototype.createElement ...

Comment: I have a similar problem with my application taking up a lot of processor time.  Did you find a fix for this so I can check if it applies to my application?

Comment: I never found an answer to this; however, my application was relatively tiny, so I just flattened it so it doesn't have nested controls. For all I know, the Angular team may have fixed it since my post. Are you using the latest script versions, and it still fails the same way in Edge?